# Golang Task Runner - (github.com/oxequa/realize) outputs exec: not started

Tags: go, task, runner

I am trying to use Golang Task Runner [realize](https://github.com/oxequa/realize) which enhance the workflow by automating the most common tasks and using the best performing Golang live reloading.

By following the Quickstart guide I did `go get github.com/oxequa/realize` in the project directory containing `go.mod` file and got following result.

```
➜ go get github.com/oxequa/realize
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210226101413-39120d07d75e
go get: gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2@none updating to
        gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2@v2.3.0: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: github.com/urfave/cli/v2
                but was required as: gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2
```

After quick ninja google searching, I found out that there was an [github issue](https://github.com/oxequa/realize/issues/269) for the same and as per [chenyongze's comment](https://github.com/oxequa/realize/issues/269#issuecomment-650832115) it was suggested to do `GO111MODULE=off go get github.com/oxequa/realize` so I had to do it and after waiting a few seconds the task runner was installed and created a `.realize.yaml` file. I then added this to `commands: {}`

```
commands:
  run:
    status: true
```

.realize.yaml now looks like this

```
settings:
  legacy:
    force: false
    interval: 0s
schema:
  - name: go-app
    path: .
    commands:
      run:
        status: true
    watcher:
      extensions:
        - go
      paths:
        - /
      ignored_paths:
        - .git
        - .realize
        - vendor
```

Next, I tried to do `realize start` as mentioned in the [README.md](https://github.com/oxequa/realize#commands-list) file.

```
➜ realize start
[18:54:58][GO-APP] : Watching 1 file/s 0 folder/s
[18:54:58][GO-APP] : Install started
[18:54:58][GO-APP] : Install 
 exec: not started
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this, it's worked for me.
The idea is to checkout to old version (v2.0.2) of realize

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export GO111MODULE=off

cd ~/
go get github.com/oxequa/realize
cd /go/src/github.com/oxequa/realize && \
  git fetch && \
  git checkout v2.0.2 && \
  go get github.com/oxequa/realize

RV=$(realize --version)
echo "Realize installed @: $RV"

export GO111MODULE=on
```